# cloning laravel project from github

Tags: php, laravel, github, composer-php

I'm new to GitHub and I found this site very useful for a lot of us. I came upon storing my Laravel project here in GitHub, but there's a problem every time I will clone it to be able to go to production, when I'm about to clone it at first, it always shows this error.

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\tourismPortal\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\tourismPortal\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\tourismPortal\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\tourismPortal\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

I know this will be solved by using composer update on it, but is there any way to prevent this error so that every time I clone it, I will go to production without encountering this error? Thanks, by the way, I'm using `tortoisegit` to clone, pull and push.

Comment: write a custom command to clone and composer update simultaneously. I think.

Comment: You can commit the vendor directory but that would defeat the purpose of composer.  Using `composer install` should be a standard after cloning a PHP project.

Comment: Not `composer update` but `composer install`. As Vishal Sh hinted, you will have to write a shell script that can actually clone and run `composer install` sequentially. A simple and well protected bash script will do the trick.

Comment: how's that? i'll write a shell script and i'll place it inside my project directory???? then it will fires automatically whenever i clone my project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can, but that is not recommended at all.

You can delete everything in `.gitignore` file and push them from a working project. Then it will work perfectly where you `git clone` them.

> But there are so many drawbacks in this way.
>   I recommend you not to do that.

Comment: Yah, I understand. The reason why I could not clone all of it is because of the list in gitignore file. This was a newbie question the time I posted it. Lol. Thanks

Comment: Is this answer seriously suggesting committing the entire `vendor` and `storage` directories to VCS?

Comment: @miken32, no. It is answering the OP's question and telling them not to do that.

Comment: gitignore help github clean and reduce unnecessary files. So you must add .gitignore file to dont upload vendor, storage, storage/*.key .env

So when you pull code from github you must run these command that Mr @yassine dotma tolk

Answer (score 182):

- Clone your project
- Go to the folder application using `cd` command on your cmd or terminal
- Run `composer install` on your cmd or terminal
- Copy `.env.example` file to `.env` on the root folder. You can type `copy .env.example .env` if using command prompt Windows or `cp .env.example .env` if using terminal, Ubuntu
- Open your `.env` file and change the database name (`DB_DATABASE`) to whatever you have, username (`DB_USERNAME`) and password (`DB_PASSWORD`) field correspond to your configuration.
- Run `php artisan key:generate`
- Run `php artisan migrate`
- Run `php artisan serve`
- Go to http://localhost:8000/

Comment: @MarianoMontañezUreta it may be, but this is not the expected answer for this post.

Comment: @MarianoMontañezUreta It's 2019 and this still the best workaround!

Comment: also you should run npm install after composer install.

Comment: This still works in March 2022 with Laravel 9. It's one of those solutions that work exactly as advertised. No errors whatsoever. Follow the steps - and presto! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 10):

1. Run `git clone 'link projer github'`
2. Run `composer install`
3. Run `cp .env.example .env` or `copy .env.example .env`
4. Run `php artisan key:generate`
5. Run `php artisan migrate`
6. Run `php artisan db:seed`
7. Run `php artisan serve`
8. Go to link [localhost:8000](https://localhost:8000) OR [127.0.0.1:8000](https://127.0.0.1:8000)

Comment: I'm not seeing what this adds to the answer left 4 years earlier by Conor.

Answer (score 4):

You guys missed a step here, after this command
`php artisan key:generate`

Don't forget to run `npm install && npm run dev`

If you have any front-end environment setup, this command will clear all the dependencies...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone's great help I also run the command to make the project work.

```
composer update
```

Comment: this is only part of the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands:

```
git clone --single-branch --branch [TAG_VERSION] https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git [CUSTOM_PROJECT_NAME]
composer install
```

Comment: How will it handle the `.env` file and `APP_KEY` ?

Comment: when you run the "composer install" it is automatically generated.
if it do not generated run at home project:
php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
php artisan key:generate