# Error cloning a Laravel Installation into Homestead - is it a database issue or a certificate issue?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

First off thanks for helping, and secondly: I'm a beginner here so thanks in advance for your patience.

OK, I have been given access to a Laravel project which I am trying to clone onto my local home environment using the bit bucket > git command.

I'm using Homestead (Laravel) for the local environment.

Downloading the repo is v simple and I'm sure that I've placed the download into the correct directory (because that is where other successfully working Laravel projects are located) but when I try to connect to the installation via a browser I get this error:

**This site can’t provide a secure connection**

Any idea about how to problem solve this?

I guess this error occurs because Homestead creates its own certificates and that is where the problem must be?

All advice and direction are gratefully received! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps and it will solve the error.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2dhJ.png]

Or just click here to see the actual link: [cloning laravel project from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602321/cloning-laravel-project-from-github)

Answer (score 0):

Reprovisioning vagrant also helps with certificate issues with cloned sites.

if you are starting up vagrant, run

```
vagrant up --provision
```

if vagrant is already started, run

```
vagrant provision
```

Comment: Thanks - now here's the crazy bit. I had it working but all the links and css/js were broken (weird) and now I ran that command and it's all offline...again...any ideas how to contineu to problem solve here? Thanks!

Comment: Is the cloned project using the asset helper to include css and js files? `{{ asset(asset_url) }}`? Also, are the css/js folder and files in there default directory? `/public`?

Comment: If the above are true, go to `/config/app.php` and insert/update this line `'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', 'fully_qualified_url_to_asset_root_directory'),`. Include the access protocol (http or https) in the url. Also make sure you have this line in the `app.php` file: `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),`

Comment: After making changes to `app.php` run the following commands in order: `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache` to reload your application and configuration caches